# Python Object Oriented Programming basic login system returns TypeError

Tags: python, file, class, oop, authentication

I was trying to make a basic login system that can log in or register the user and store the info in a text file. Yet, as a beginner, I'm facing a problem to which I couldn't find any solution.

So I defined my class and functions that I want to make:

```py
class User():
    def __init__(self, username, password, email):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.email = email

    def login(self, username, password):
        self.username = input("Enter username: ")
        self.password = input("Enter password: ")
        with open("register.txt", "r", encoding=utf-8) as file:
            if username == username and password == password:
                print("login successful!")

    def register(self, username, password, email):
        self.username = input("Enter username: ")
        self.password = input("Enter password: ")
        self.pass_check = input("Enter password: ")
        self.email = input("Enter email: ")

        if password == pass_check:
            print("Password match, you can login")
            with open("register.txt", "a", encoding=utf-8) as file:
                file.write('Username:', username+' ', 'Password:',
                           password+' ', 'email:', email)
        else:
            print("passwords don't match")
```

Secondly added a simple code for using these functions:

```py
choice = int(input("1-Login  2-Register"))
if choice == 1:
    User.login()
elif choice == 2:
    User.register()
```

When i run this code i get this error:

```py
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Python Projects/login-oop.py", line 32, in <module > User.login()
TypeError: login() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'self', 'username', and 'password'
```

I searched for hours and I think it's very fundamental but I couldn't find any solution.

Comment: How/where are you initializing the object for  `User` class?

Answer (score 0):

In the following piece of code, you are calling `User.login()` but in your method definition, you have `def login(self, username, password)`. You need to pass `username` and `password` argument to the `User.login()`.

```py
choice = int(input("1-Login  2-Register"))
if choice == 1:     
    User.login()
elif choice ==2:
    User.register()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your login function requires two arguments. You are providing none. You need something like:

```
""" declared some instance of a User as my_user somewhere else in the code """

username = 'some username'
password = 'password'

my_user.login(username, password)
```

Comment: You can't use the `User` class directly.  You'll have to declare an _instance_ of the class and then call `.login()` on the instance.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes of course, I don't know what I was thinking. It's good to be explicit, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code useful you should use your properties (username, password etc.) as **private's properties** by:

```
self.nameProperty = nameProperty
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29990579)